# Sorting a C++ list by multiple columns

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I have a C++ list object with 4 columns of data where each column is separated by a white space. They are of type string, integer, integer, and double respectively. How do I sort the list by the first column, and then by the fourth column?

Comment: Some code would be good here.  When you say a C++ list, what do you mean?  An STL vector, list, or some home made list?  You will probably want to overload an operator for your data object, but exactly how will depend on your implementation

Comment: I mean an STL list of an object with four properties. The properties are of type string, integer, integer, and double respectively

Answer (score 4):

Use a predicate function that parses data and return the result of less-than by comparing object 1 and object 2.

```
struct sorter1432
{
   bool operator()(const Data &a, const Data &b)
   {
      if(a.first != b.first) return a.first < b.first  // string comparision
      if(a.fourth != b.fourth) return a.fourth < b.fourth  // double comparision
      if(a.third != b.third) return a.third < b.third  // int comparision
      if(a.second != b.second) return a.second < b.second  // int comparision
      return false;  // Equal
   }
};
...
lst.sort(sorter1432);
```

About the members first, second, third and fourth you parse (using [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) possibly) and store this in the data members as parsing every time in your helper function may be costly.

Comment: 1.  I think you mean if (a.first != b.first)...  2. He probably wants to overload the < operator.

Comment: @SignalEleven Right thanks. Yes unless he may later want to sort in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Make a struct of the data and then sort according to Mohits' answer. 
it could look like

```
struct s_data{
string str;
int a;
int b;
double c;
};
```

now you can sort by using a functor.

to input use a stringstream (will make life much easier).